# Reformat seaborn axis tick labels (datetime and scientific notation)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I am trying to plot a bar chart. However, the number on x-axis shows 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 and y-axis shows the np datetime.

I want the x-axis shows the exactly number and y-axis shows the date with dd-mm-yy only. May I know how can I solve it?

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime

dateToday = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# Only get the adjusted close.
tickers = data.DataReader(['NFLX'],
                       start='', 
                       end=dateToday, 
                       data_source='yahoo')['Volume'][-50:]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

# Change the style of the figure to the "dark" theme
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

plt.title('Returns')
sns.barplot(y=tickers.index,x=tickers['NFLX'],color='b',edgecolor='w',label='7d_returns',orient = 'h')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the date formatting, you can supply a formatted index: `y=tickers.index.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`
2. For the `x` axis, they are currently in scientific notation (note the `1e7` in the bottom right corner), so you can disable the scientific notation: `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x')`

```py
sns.barplot(y=tickers.index.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), x=tickers['NFLX'], color='b', edgecolor='w', label='7d_returns', orient='h')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x')
```

[image: output with fixed x- and y-axis]

Comment: So nice. Thanks for your help.