# How to specify the datetime format of tick labels in a Seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, datetime, seaborn

How do I format the following string to shorter format.
I have a list of strings that have the following shape

```
2022-06-03T17:00:00.000000000
2022-06-04T09:40:00.000000000
2022-06-05T02:20:00.000000000
2022-06-05T19:00:00.000000000
2022-06-06T11:40:00.000000000
2022-06-07T04:20:00.000000000
2022-06-07T21:00:00.000000000
2022-06-08T13:40:00.000000000
2022-06-09T06:20:00.000000000
```

They're taken from `ax.get_xticklabels()` since I want to format `xticklabels()`.

I want the following format: e.g. `2022-06-09 17:00`.

Now, I could use the following trick loop over each and `tick.get_text()[:16].replace('T', ' ')` which gives me:

```
2022-06-03 17:00
2022-06-04 09:40
2022-06-05 02:20
2022-06-05 19:00
2022-06-06 11:40
2022-06-07 04:20
2022-06-07 21:00
2022-06-08 13:40
2022-06-09 06:20
```

But is there another, cleaner, simpler, way?

Comment: Have you tried using `strptime` and `strftime`? Maybe just configure the axis ticks to use the correct format to begin with?

Comment: I have tried but it failed. I wanted to reduce the frequency of ticks and the only way that works in Seaborn was to set the frequency this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560761/seaborn-heatmap-setting-frequency-of-datetime-ytick-labels

Because of that using strftime didn't work.

Comment: What you have shown is about *where* the ticks are, not about how they are formatted.

Comment: There are examples for how to specify the format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67237923/reformat-seaborn-axis-tick-labels-datetime-and-scientific-notation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105648/ordering-and-formatting-dates-on-x-axis-in-seaborn-bar-plot).

Comment: I tried to explain the origin of the problem, where it all started and why I arrived to where I did.

Comment: The thing is in Seaborn heatmap I can't specify the index as for a barchart with `strftime`. Moreover, the index in the dataframe I'm using had the format that I already wanted but for some reason in Seaborn it was altered.

Comment: Assuming you are using pandas, the easiest option is to set the format in the dataframe column before plotting the heatmap.

Answer (score 0):

```
import dateutil.parser


dt_strs = [
'2022-06-03T17:00:00.000000000',
'2022-06-04T09:40:00.000000000',
'2022-06-05T02:20:00.000000000',
'2022-06-05T19:00:00.000000000',
'2022-06-06T11:40:00.000000000',
'2022-06-07T04:20:00.000000000',
'2022-06-07T21:00:00.000000000',
'2022-06-08T13:40:00.000000000',
'2022-06-09T06:20:00.000000000',
]

for dt_str in dt_strs:
    print(dateutil.parser.isoparse(dt_str).strftime("%Y-%M-%d %H:%M"))
```

Output:

```
2022-00-03 17:00
2022-40-04 09:40
2022-20-05 02:20
2022-00-05 19:00
2022-40-06 11:40
2022-20-07 04:20
2022-00-07 21:00
2022-40-08 13:40
2022-20-09 06:20
```